# Hg forget + ignore without deleting files on update

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I want to forget and ignore a certain file in a mercurial repo, so that the file would not get deleted not only in my working copy but also in a peer developer's repo, when they pull my change and do an update. (A common case is, e.g., Eclipse's .classpath file, when you want it to be managed solely by Gradle from now on, but do not want to force devs to reimport the project.)

Is there any possibility to do this? Maybe there is something like this in other VCSs?

Answer (score 1):

Check `hg forget`:

From its help entry:

> (...) This only removes files from the current branch, not from the
>   entire project history, and it does not delete them from the working directory. (...)

Comment: `hg forget` only works in my working copy. My question is about the same behaviour in peer devs' repos after `hg update`.

Comment: Right, indeed that removes the forgotten file on another repo. Those people can however restore and then also forget the file using revert: `hg revert -rPREVIOUS removed.file; hg forget removed.file`. It's not as elegant, though and requires everyone to do this